# Flutter - Where is it appropriate to use class members in initializers?

Tags: flutter

I am writing a stateful flutter widget. This widget takes, as constructor properties, 3 urls.

```
class AvatarWithOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  final githubURL;
  final linkedinURL;
  final twitterURL;

  AvatarWithOverlay({this.githubURL, this.linkedinURL, this.twitterURL});

  @override
  _AvatarWithOverlayState createState() => _AvatarWithOverlayState();
}
```

In it's state I'm attempting to utilize those values to build buttons which launch the urls.

```
class _AvatarWithOverlayState extends State<AvatarWithOverlay>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  _AvatarWithOverlayState();

  AnimationController controller;
  List<Widget> buttons;
  final multipliers = [Offset(.5, 1.0), Offset(1.0, .6), Offset(1.0, 0)];
  var animating = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    buttons = [
      buildButton(widget.githubURL),
      buildButton(widget.linkedinURL),
      buildButton(widget.twitterURL)
    ];
  }
```

The above code works.

If however, I was to move the button array definition outside of "initState", I get a editor error.

```
class _AvatarWithOverlayState extends State<AvatarWithOverlay>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  _AvatarWithOverlayState();

  AnimationController controller;
  var buttons = [
    buildButton(widget.githubURL),
    buildButton(widget.linkedinURL),
    buildButton(widget.twitterURL)
  ];
```

The above code produces the errors: "implicit_this_referenced_in_initializer"

What is special about "initState" that the error is not present there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dart you cannot access instance members in an initializer i.e. you are not allowed to put code directly in the class definition. This is what you are trying to do when you put button array definition outside of 'initState'. In Dart, while creating an object the variables are set in two steps. All variables are defined in the class at the same time in the initialization step. Next the constructor code is run. This is the reason why you cannot point to other variables within the class definition while declaring another variable since the other variable **has not yet come into existence**. Whereas when you define the buttons list in 'initState' function all the variables have now been defined and have come into existence.